# Can i know why this happen during animating and how to solve it?

Tags: animation

[image]

In pose mode, I move the y-axis up and insert a keyframe and this was happening as the picture that I have uploaded.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that sumarizes the issue in the question

Comment: Looks like you've missed a vertex when weight painting, but as Duarte said, please edit your question, a good title attracts good answers.

Answer (score 0):

That part of the mesh isn't affected by bone movement coz it might have been missed in the vertex painting. select the bone which caused it and edit the weight paint. add some to weight to the mesh. It should get back together.